# Need to generate a Landscape Table with Multi Rows

Tags: tables, landscape

I'm trying to create a landscape table for a medication list. I tried coding for it on Tex, its been more than a year since I did anything with it, and the Excel table is just too big. Please could someone help me out with the rows have multi rows inside them. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{makecell, multirow} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!35} 
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Medication + 2pt} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{25pt} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth }{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |*{26}{ c|}} 
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rothead{\textbf{Medication}}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Acetazolamide}} & \rothead{\textbf{Carbamazepine}}  
& \rothead{\textbf{Clobazam}} & \rothead{\textbf{Clonazepam} } & 

\rothead{\textbf{Ethosuximide}} & \rothead{\textbf{Gabapentin}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Lacosamide}}& \rothead{\textbf{Lamotrigine}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Levetiracetam}} & \rothead{\textbf{Nitrazepam}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Oxcarbazepine}} & \rothead{\textbf{Perampanel}}& 
\rothead{\textbf{ Phenobaritone}} & \rothead{\textbf{Phenytoin}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Piracetam}} & \rothead{\textbf{Prednisolone}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Pregabalin}} & \rothead{\textbf{Rufinamide}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Sodium Valproate}} & \rothead{\textbf{Stiripentol}} 
&\rothead{\textbf{Tiagabine}} &     \rothead{\textbf{Topiramate}} & 
\rothead{\textbf{Vigabatrin}} & \rothead{\textbf{Zonisamide}} \\ 
\hline 
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!35} 
\multirowcell{-0.35}{\textbf{Visit 1}} 
& \textbf{Date} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-26} 
& \textbf{Dose} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\multirowcell{-0.35}{\textbf{Visit 2}} 
& \textbf{Date} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-26} 
& \textbf{Dose} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\multirowcell{-0.35}{\textbf{Visit 3}} 
& \textbf{Date} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-26} 
& \textbf{Dose} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\multirowcell{-0.35}{\textbf{Visit 4}} 
& \textbf{Date} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-26} 
& \textbf{Dose} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\multirowcell{-0.35}{\textbf{Visit 5}} 
& \textbf{Date} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-26} 
& \textbf{Dose} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\multirowcell{-0.35}{\textbf{Visit 6}} 
& \textbf{Date} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-26} 
& \textbf{Dose} & & & & & & & & & & & 
& & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular*} 
\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I've gotten here, but I really want to finish this on Tex and not Microsoft. I'm not sure if this feasible anymore, as I've been trying to extend the margins to go all the way and not halfway.

Comment: Where are the multirows? Anyway, this table can't fit the text height, unless you reduce  the value of `\tacolsep` and use a smaller font size. Perhaps it would be easier re-organising the structure of the table, if that is possible.

Comment: Your code declares two columns but uses twenty-four!

Comment: Fixed, thanks! Though now theres a problem with the midrule

Comment: @Ar1229: The table in your example still specifies one column less than used. Additionally, the `booktabs` package is missing (needed for `\midrule`).  Apart from that, please note that `\begin{center}` inside `\begin{table}` causes unwanted white space. To avoid this and still horizontally center your table, you can use the `\centering` command.

Comment: @Ar1229, any news? as i see, you upload new mwe which is almost the same as my answer. actually you only degrade my code (why?) and  add row colors, by this you change your first question ... what is in my answer not fulfill your expectation? you also not respond to my chat effort ... now is not clear what you like to have, consequently i will suggest to close your question as "unclear".

Comment: @Zarko hi Zarko. If you see the edit, I clearly mention "with the help of @Zarko..", so it is Your code. I sent you this via the chat box too, but you did not respond, and it's been three days and I needed help with the code. I don't see how adding colours to anything is degrading, but that's your opinion. My question is simple: Can the margins please extend all the way in and not stop after the 21st column. Your code was really close, but it is still incomplete.

Comment: @Ar1229, sorry, but u respond later and wait on you. however, today i will have tie after 22:30 o'clock of gmt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**:
after infornation got in chat it seems that you looking for something like this:

[image]

since document contain only your table, the code can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,
            margin=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, multirow}
\newcommand\rothead[1]{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\textbf{#1\ }}}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{8pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{8pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8mm}}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{LightGray}
\begin{tabular}{| l | Sl | *{24}{C|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rothead{Medication}}
    & \rothead{Acetazolamide}       & \rothead{Carbamazepine}
    & \rothead{Clobazam}            & \rothead{Clonazepam}
    & \rothead{Ethosuximide}        & \rothead{Gabapentin}
    & \rothead{Lacosamide}          & \rothead{Lamotrigine}
    & \rothead{Levetiracetam}       & \rothead{Nitrazepam}
    & \rothead{Oxcarbazepine}       & \rothead{Perampanel}
    & \rothead{ Phenobaritone}      & \rothead{Phenytoin}
    & \rothead{Piracetam}           & \rothead{Prednisolone}
    & \rothead{Pregabalin}          & \rothead{Rufinamide}
    & \rothead{Sodium Valproate}    & \rothead{Stiripentol}
    & \rothead{Tiagabine}           & \rothead{Topiramate}
    & \rothead{Vigabatrin}          & \rothead{Zonisamide}  \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!35}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 1}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 2}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 3}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 4}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 5}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 6}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 7 }
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 8}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{|*{26}{-|}}
    & Dose  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        &      \\
    \hhline{~|*{25}{-|}}
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{Visit 9}
    & Date  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &
    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

your table is really huge. you should consider to split it in two parts with 14 columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80334/discussion-between-ar1229-and-zarko).

Answer (score 1):

Why not transpose the table? Assuming that the contents of the cells that you did not show are also short, you can display the same amount of information without having to rotate the table and the column headers. In the following example, I have used the rules from the `booktabs` packages in combination with some white space (after every fourth row) to guide the eye:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}
\toprule
 Medication & \multicolumn{2}{c}{V1}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{V2}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{V3}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{V4}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{V5}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{V6}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(lr){12-13} 
 Ac & C & D & C & D & C & D & C & D & C & D & C & D \\
 Ca \\
 Clo \\
 Clon \\[3pt]
 Etho \\
 Gaba \\
 Laco \\
 Lamo \\[3pt]
 Lev \\
 Nit \\
 Ox \\
 Per \\[3pt]
 Pheno \\
 Phen \\
 Pi \\
 Pre \\[3pt]
 Preg \\
 Ru \\
 So \\
 Stirip \\[3pt]
 Tia \\
 Top \\
 Vig \\
 Zo \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I can't transpose the table, as it needs to be in a landscape format.